# How to create custom events in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to create custom events in javascript like onclick event . i want to create a event as onlogin & how to pass custom data to the newly created event & how to add callback function to the this event.

Comment: have you tried anything? please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer the create custom event part.. the "Dispatch" will be fired when you want it to.

in JS web api's there's a ready-made `CustomEvent()` constructor.

### Example

```js
// add an appropriate event listener
obj.addEventListener("cat", function(e) { process(e.detail) });

// create and dispatch the event
var event = new CustomEvent("cat", {
  detail: {
    hazcheeseburger: true
  }
});
obj.dispatchEvent(event);
```

For more info. go to [MDN customEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)

Answer (score 0):

Basically there's no class in JavaScript, all you need is Functions, can assign a function to another by a variable,

```
  var MyClass = (function(){

        var static_var = 1;

        var MyClass = function ( callback ) {

            var privateVar;
            var privateFn = function(){ alert('Im private!'); };

            this.someProperty = 5;
            this.someFunction = function () {
                alert('Im public!');
            };
            this.say = function() {
                alert('Num ' + this.someProperty);
                callback();
            }
            this.alter = function() {
                this.someProperty ++;
            }
        };

        return MyClass;

    })();

    TheClass = new MyClass(function() {
        alert('Event!');
    });

    TheClass.say();
```

Please click the example in JSFiddler - http://jsfiddle.net/9pCmh/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can make use of their take on [custom events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/).  These events can be bound and triggered just like typical browser events.
Note that they also allow you to specify custom data that is made available to the event handler.

Example:
$('my-selector').on('myApp:myEvent', function() { /* code here*/ });

$('my-selector').trigger('myApp:myCustomEvent');